# Connet to websocket with cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have to connect to websocket, but it's work only after authorization. I think that I should set cookies and headers. How can I do it?

```
var http = require("http");
const WebSocket = require("ws");
var options = {
    hostname: "old.cs.money",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
        Cookie: "_csrf=csrf",
    },
};
var results = "";
var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
    var socket = new WebSocket("wss://ws.cs.money/ws");
    socket.on("connect", () => {
        console.log("connected");
    });
    socket.on("message", (msg) => {
        console.log(msg);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should do the job:

```
new WebSocket("wss://ws.cs.money/ws", {
  headers: {},
});
```

On my own opinion try to avoid cookies and work with JWT tokens